# After moving SUPEE-6788 to production Aheadworks follow up email module does not work

Tags: magento-1.9

Today I moved the Aheadworks follow up email module after fixing it for the admin router modifications as suggested in SUPEE-6788 patch documentation.

```
  <followupemail_admin>
    <use>admin</use>
    <args>
        <module>AW_Followupemail</module>
        <frontName>followupemail_admin</frontName>
    </args>
</followupemail_admin>
```

to

```
<adminhtml>
    <args>
        <modules>
            <followupemail_admin before="Mage_Adminhtml">AW_Followupemail_Adminhtml</followupemail_admin>
        </modules>
    </args>
</adminhtml>
```

But it started redirecting to blank page whenever click on any menu item related to Follow up module.

Though I had tested it in dev and staging server.

**NOTE :**  Posted this question for others as a reference if they face similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much digging in the code when I informed about the issue to the site owner. The reply was that the module is disabled in the admin and I was not aware of this fact. The some sections of module were still accessible.

See the screen shot attached.

[image]

Some times deployment issues are not because of code :)